# automatically email invoice and shipment after creating

Tags: invoice, shipment

How can I make magento automatically email `invoice/shipment` after I create them.

what happens now is that:

1) **I a create the invoice/shipment and then**

2) **I open the invoice/shipment and press send email.**

I don't want to do the second step, I want the email to be send once the invoice/shipment created.

Comment: is this Magento behavior actually normal ?? or do I have some sort of a problem ??

Comment: Yes, you should be able to have emails send immediately once they are created, it's core behaviour. Which version are you running? If it's a recent version, do you have the Magento cron job configured and running correctly?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13285003/2812842

Comment: I have magento 1.9.2.4. cron job is running without a problem

Answer (score 2):

you need to look at this magento event `sales_order_shipment_save_after`.

So in app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml:

```
...
<events>
    <sales_order_shipment_save_after>
    <observers>
        <namespace_module>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
        <method>autoEmail</method>
        </namespace_module>
    </observers>
    </sales_order_shipment_save_after>
</events>
....
```

and in app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model/Observer.php:

```
    <?php
    class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer
    {
       public function autoEmail($observer) {
           $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
           $order = $shipment->getOrder();
// your email triggering code here.
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason, it is a very silly mistake

when I create the invoice/shipment I don't click (Email Copy of invoice/Shipment).

I was thinking this will send a copy of the email to me, but when I tried it out. I found it is for sending a copy to the customer